# JupyterHub does not connect to its public port

Tags: python, proxy, jupyterhub

JupyterHub not working on public port 8000. It only works on port 8081.
Everywhere I read, everyone got their issues magically solved without any solutions.

https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/742

```
jupyterhub_config.py

from oauthenticator.gitlab import GitLabOAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GitLabOAuthenticator
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/hub/oauth_callback'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.client_id =  '...'
c.GitLabOAuthenticator.client_secret = '...'
c.ConfigurableHTTPProxy.debug = True
c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = '127.0.0.1'
c.JupyterHub.hub_port = 8081
c.JupyterHub.ip = '127.0.0.1'
c.JupyterHub.port = 8000
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'simplespawner.SimpleLocalProcessSpawner'
c.JupyterHub.ssl_cert = '/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.crt'
c.JupyterHub.ssl_key = '/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.key'
```

Using GitLab as the authenticator and simplespawner as the spawner. Not using Docker.

JupyterHub -V 0.9.4

Configurable-HTTP-Proxy -V 4.0.1

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I have to run the following line on another terminal window before JupyterHub.

Run:

```
configurable-http-proxy --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8000 --api-ip=127.0.0.1 --api-port=8001
```

before:

```
jupyterhub -f /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py --debug
```